# Seeking in-app purchase helper class

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase

I am using the `UIStoreKit` to implement the in app purchase on the App Store.

I have heard once that there is some helper class on the net that can help with everything behind the scenes, so I can just use simple methods to use it .

I can't remember or find the name. I would be happy for direction to a popular class to help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can see the followings links:

http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.fr/2012/04/implementing-inapp-purchase-in-xcode.html
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

Comment: I am familier with ray's class, but i was talking about something else. thanks anyway, i will search for it and put it here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it.
Its called `MKStorekit`
There are guides [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/introducing-mkstorekit-%E2%80%93-version-3/) and [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/)

> MKStoreKit [Github link](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit)

Comment: I dont see why people have downvoted this. Its actually the best answer!